# Java 1.6 + BouncyCastle + TLS1.2 (handshake_failure(40))

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, tls1.2

In my case, I have Java 1.6 and want to connect to a remote server which only supports TLS1.2. Server URL is: https://blagajne-test.fu.gov.si:9002 and certificate public key is here: http://datoteke.durs.gov.si/dpr/files/test-tls.cer

I have no possibility to upgrade Java because is a part of Oracle Database 11g (11.4).

I tried to write a simple program in Java which uses BouncyCastel libraries but got error: Exception in thread "main"

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsFatalAlertReceived: handshake_failure(40)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.handleAlertMessage(Unknown Source)
```

The step I have followed was:

1.) have downloaded test-tls.cer and imported the key into jssacerts and cacerts.
[image]

2.) In Java have done this example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.CertificateRequest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DefaultTlsClient;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsAuthentication;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsCredentials;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class Test3 {

    public static Signature podpis = null;
    public static MessageDigest md = null;

    static {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String httpsURL = "https://blagajne-test.fu.gov.si:9002";
        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);      
        HttpsURLConnection  con = (HttpsURLConnection )myurl.openConnection();
        con.setSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketConnectionFactory());   
        InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();

    }
}
```

and

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedEvent;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSessionContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.Certificate;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.CertificateRequest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DefaultTlsClient;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.ExtensionType;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsAuthentication;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsCredentials;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class TLSSocketConnectionFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Adding Custom BouncyCastleProvider
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    static {
        if (Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null) {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        }
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//SECURE RANDOM
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private SecureRandom _secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Adding Custom BouncyCastleProvider
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, final String host, int port, boolean arg3)
            throws IOException {
        if (socket == null) {
            socket = new Socket();
        }
        if (!socket.isConnected()) {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        }

        final TlsClientProtocol tlsClientProtocol = new TlsClientProtocol(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream(), _secureRandom);

        return _createSSLSocket(host, tlsClientProtocol);

    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SOCKET FACTORY  METHODS  
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host,
            int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host,
            int port) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host,
            int port,
            InetAddress localHost,
            int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address,
            int port,
            InetAddress localAddress,
            int localPort) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//SOCKET CREATION
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private SSLSocket _createSSLSocket(final String host, final TlsClientProtocol tlsClientProtocol) {
        return new SSLSocket() {
            private java.security.cert.Certificate[] peertCerts;

            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                return tlsClientProtocol.getInputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                return tlsClientProtocol.getOutputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
                tlsClientProtocol.close();
            }

            @Override
            public void addHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean getEnableSessionCreation() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getEnabledCipherSuites() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getEnabledProtocols() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getNeedClientAuth() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public SSLSession getSession() {
                return new SSLSession() {

                    @Override
                    public int getApplicationBufferSize() {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getCipherSuite() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getCreationTime() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getId() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getLastAccessedTime() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.Certificate[] getLocalCertificates() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Principal getLocalPrincipal() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getPacketBufferSize() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public X509Certificate[] getPeerCertificateChain()
                            throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.Certificate[] getPeerCertificates() throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException {
                        return peertCerts;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getPeerHost() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getPeerPort() {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Principal getPeerPrincipal() throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException {
                        return null;
                        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getProtocol() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public SSLSessionContext getSessionContext() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getValue(String arg0) {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String[] getValueNames() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void invalidate() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isValid() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putValue(String arg0, Object arg1) {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeValue(String arg0) {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                };
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getSupportedProtocols() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getUseClientMode() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean getWantClientAuth() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void removeHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void setEnableSessionCreation(boolean arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void setNeedClientAuth(boolean arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void setUseClientMode(boolean arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void setWantClientAuth(boolean arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void startHandshake() throws IOException {

                tlsClientProtocol.connect(new DefaultTlsClient() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public Hashtable<Integer, byte[]> getClientExtensions() throws IOException {
                        Hashtable<Integer, byte[]> clientExtensions = super.getClientExtensions();
                        if (clientExtensions == null) {
                            clientExtensions = new Hashtable<Integer, byte[]>();
                        }

                        //Add host_name
                        byte[] host_name = host.getBytes();

                        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
                        dos.writeShort(host_name.length + 3);
                        dos.writeByte(0); // 
                        dos.writeShort(host_name.length);
                        dos.write(host_name);
                        dos.close();
                        clientExtensions.put(ExtensionType.server_name, baos.toByteArray());
                        return clientExtensions;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public TlsAuthentication getAuthentication()
                            throws IOException {
                        return new TlsAuthentication() {

                            @Override
                            public void notifyServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate) throws IOException {

                                try {
                                    KeyStore ks = _loadKeyStore();

                                    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                                    List<java.security.cert.Certificate> certs = new LinkedList<java.security.cert.Certificate>();
                                    boolean trustedCertificate = false;
                                    for (org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate c : serverCertificate.getCertificateList()) {
                                        java.security.cert.Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(c.getEncoded()));
                                        certs.add(cert);

                                        String alias = ks.getCertificateAlias(cert);
                                        if (alias != null) {
                                            if (cert instanceof java.security.cert.X509Certificate) {
                                                try {
                                                    ((java.security.cert.X509Certificate) cert).checkValidity();
                                                    trustedCertificate = true;

                                                } catch (CertificateExpiredException cee) {
                                                    cee.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("-->");
                                        }

                                    }
                                    if (!trustedCertificate) {
                                        throw new CertificateException("Unknown cert " + serverCertificate);
                                    }
                                    peertCerts = certs.toArray(new java.security.cert.Certificate[0]);
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                    throw new IOException(ex);
                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public TlsCredentials getClientCredentials(CertificateRequest arg0)
                                    throws IOException {
                                return null;
                            }

                            /**
                             * Private method to load keyStore with system or
                             * default properties.
                             *
                             * @return
                             * @throws Exception
                             */
                            private KeyStore _loadKeyStore() throws Exception {
                                FileInputStream trustStoreFis = null;
                                try {
                                    String sysTrustStore = null;
                                    File trustStoreFile = null;

                                    KeyStore localKeyStore = null;

                                    sysTrustStore = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
                                    String javaHome;
                                    if (!"NONE".equals(sysTrustStore)) {
                                        if (sysTrustStore != null) {
                                            trustStoreFile = new File(sysTrustStore);
                                            trustStoreFis = _getFileInputStream(trustStoreFile);
                                        } else {
                                            javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
                                            trustStoreFile = new File(javaHome + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "security" + File.separator + "jssecacerts");

                                            if ((trustStoreFis = _getFileInputStream(trustStoreFile)) == null) {
                                                trustStoreFile = new File(javaHome + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "security" + File.separator + "cacerts");
                                                trustStoreFis = _getFileInputStream(trustStoreFile);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        if (trustStoreFis != null) {
                                            sysTrustStore = trustStoreFile.getPath();
                                        } else {
                                            sysTrustStore = "No File Available, using empty keystore.";
                                        }
                                    }

                                    System.out.println("sysTrustStore: " +sysTrustStore);

                                    String trustStoreType = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType") != null ? System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType") : KeyStore.getDefaultType();
                                    String trustStoreProvider = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider") != null ? System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider") : "";

                                    if (trustStoreType.length() != 0) {
                                        if (trustStoreProvider.length() == 0) {
                                            localKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustStoreType);
                                        } else {
                                            localKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustStoreType, trustStoreProvider);
                                        }

                                        char[] keyStorePass = null;
                                        String str5 = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword") != null ? System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword") : "";

                                        if (str5.length() != 0) {
                                            keyStorePass = str5.toCharArray();
                                        }

                                        localKeyStore.load(trustStoreFis, (char[]) keyStorePass);

                                        if (keyStorePass != null) {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < keyStorePass.length; i++) {
                                                keyStorePass[i] = 0;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return (KeyStore) localKeyStore;
                                } finally {
                                    if (trustStoreFis != null) {
                                        trustStoreFis.close();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            private FileInputStream _getFileInputStream(File paramFile) throws Exception {
                                if (paramFile.exists()) {
                                    return new FileInputStream(paramFile);
                                }
                                return null;
                            }

                        };

                    }

                });

            }

        };//Socket

    }

}
```

When I execute the main program I got: [image]

What I'm doing wrong or why I get back that exception?

Comment: I am also struggling in same, did u got it working

Comment: Yes, have solved with: Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS",new BouncyCastleJsseProvider()); Also have a look here: [First link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4106349)
[Second link](https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BC-FJA-(D)TLSUserGuide-1.0.3.pdf)
[Third link](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BCFipsIn100.pdf)
[Fourth link](https://boredwookie.net/blog/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-lightweight-api-s-tlsclient)

Comment: @Ferguson: I have the exact same code, and I have imported necessary certs onto my java cacerts but when I try to connect to endpoint URL i get below error. Have you come across this before?

Exception in thread "Main Thread" org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40)
 at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.AbstractTlsPeer.notifySecureRenegotiation(Unknown Source)

Comment: No.. have not. :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Download jce_policy-6.zip from oracle website
2. unzip the jce_policy-6.zip you will have two jars local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar.
3. Install the jars based on the README file provided in the zip - two jars should be copied to `%JAVA_HOME%/lib/security`
4. Edit the file `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/java.security` and locate the security-provider list add this line -
   `security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`
5. Use the following code to get the SSLContext.

   ```
    Provider provider = new BouncyCastleJsseProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS",provider.getName());
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Please switch to Version 1.55 this will fix the issue...