# Java 1.6_u45 + BouncyCastle + TLS1.2 throws handshake_failure(40) (notifySecureRenegotiation)

Tags: java, bouncycastle, tls1.2, java-6

My case is almost close to [Another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405702/java-1-6-bouncycastle-tls1-2-handshake-failure40)

I am on JDK1.6_u45 trying to connect to a https endpoint that is on TLS1.2 using BouncyCastle.
I have added the endpoint public key certificate onto cacerts under jre/lib/security

However the error I get follows different stack trace as shown below:

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.AbstractTlsPeer.notifySecureRenegotiation(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol.receiveServerHelloMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
at TLSSocketConnectionFactory$1.startHandshake(TLSSocketConnectionFactory.java:498)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:167)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
at CopyOfTest.getResponseJsonString(CopyOfTest.java:40)
at CopyOfTest.main(CopyOfTest.java:15)
```

The BouncyCastle TLSSocketConnectionFactory is same as the one provided in this link, so let me not post it here again. (link: [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405702/java-1-6-bouncycastle-tls1-2-handshake-failure40)

My test class is as below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class CopyOfTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        //below url is a not an actual endpoint. 
        URL url = new URL(
                "https://abc.def.ghi/Customer/v1/nonexistantlink/?postalCode=80120&clientId=ABC");
        String returnData = getResponseJsonString(url);
        System.out.println("returnData: " + returnData);
        ArrayNameDescDTO msg = new Gson().fromJson(returnData,
                ArrayNameDescDTO.class);
        System.out.println(msg.toString());


    }

    private static String getResponseJsonString(URL url) throws IOException {

//      Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
//       SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS",new BouncyCastleJsseProvider())

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketConnectionFactory());

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        byte[] message = ("username" + ":" + "andItsPassword").getBytes("UTF-8");
        String encoded = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(message);
        System.out.println("encoded: Basic " + encoded);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10 sec

        conn.connect();
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        switch (status) {
        case 200:
        case 201:
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            return sb.toString();
        }

        conn.disconnect();
        return null;

    }
}
```

Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: what versions of bouncycastle libraries are you using?

Comment: It's a bit of a slosh through the BC source code and RFC 5246, but it looks like the server does not support secure renegotiation. It is required to do so by the TLS 1.2 speciication, so the BC TLS client aborts the handshake.

Comment: I have tried with both 'bcprov-jdk15on-164' & 'bcprov-jdk16-1.46'. Ended up getting the same error.

Comment: I found something about RFC 5746 on this site : "http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/TlsClientProtocol-and-TLSv1-0-td4658381.html" . Here the person says "just override 'notifySecureRenegotiation' method in client and do nothing in that method" but TLSSocketConnectionFactory doesnt seem to have this method to override so I am puzzled as to where the OP added this override method to get it working for him.

Comment: I thought that was the answer after looking through the source code. I think the place to do it is somewhere in the `createSocket()` method override but I didn't immediately figure out how to do that. If I get a chance later I'll look again.

Comment: I think you can follow the example in your [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405702/java-1-6-bouncycastle-tls1-2-handshake-failure40) with a slight modification. In the overridden `startHandshake()` method you'll see that the BC tls protocol instance is started with an instance of `DefaultTlsClient`. You need to subclass `DefaultTlsClient` to override the `notifySecureRenegotiation()` method.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk, you are a life saver!!. After making the above changes my program works great. Thank you so much!!. I don't know how to mark your comment as answer here.

Comment: I'm glad things worked out! I may write an answer in the next day or two, but it would great if you could write an answer to your own question. Include enough detail so that someone coming along later with the same problem can understand and apply the modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is provided by @James Reinstate Monica Polk. I am reposting the solution here just so that others can benefit from it.

The solution is to create a New TLS client which extends 'org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DefaultTlsClient' and override the method 'notifySecureRenegotiation'. 
Something like below:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DefaultTlsClient;

public class NewDefaultTlsClient extends DefaultTlsClient{

    @Override
    public void notifySecureRenegotiation(boolean secureRenegotiation){
        //do nothing here
    }

    @Override
    public org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.TlsAuthentication getAuthentication()
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now on the TLSSocketConnectionFactory, go to startHandshake() method, and change the

```
tlsClientProtocol.connect(new DefaultTlsClient(){ ....
```

with

```
tlsClientProtocol.connect(new NewDefaultTlsClient(){ ....
```

Thats it!. After the above change the said error stops showing up and the JDK6 code is able to hit the TLS1.2 endpoints.